# Database migration with strapi

Tags: database, migration, strapi

Is there a way to configure Strapi to generate database migration scripts?
Or do I have to write myself knex up/down function?

I imagine that by adding a collection for example, a database table is added and so a migration script is automatically generated normally.

I don't have that.

Am I missing something?
Or strapi doesn't generate that migration scripts and doesn't handle them?

Thx